# CodeIgniter project not work on Linux-based remote server

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, codeigniter

I developed a project with CodeIgniter on windows XAMPP which works. But does not work on Linux-based remote server.

**I get the error:**

> Unable to load the requested file: home.php

**Controller:** home.php:

```
public function index(){
  $this->load->view('home');
}
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Are you calling the home.php file directly or including on another php file? Enable the logs on your php and http server and check. Looks like your script is not finding the file on the path you defined. Try to use the full path for file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On codeIgniter 3 + versions a couple of checks to do if getting errors below.

---

- error 404 page not found
- Unable to load the requested file

---

> **Check first.**

- Make sure your file name has the first letter upper case only
- Make sure your class name has first letter upper case only
- This applies for models as well.

**Warning:** Some times even though lower case may work on some localhost some other operating systems it may cause error when file or class are lower case, it may not be the same for everyone.

[*Controller*](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

**File name:** Home.php

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_example');
     }

     public function index(){
        // $data['results'] = $this->model_example->get_results();
        $this->load->view('home');
     }
}
```

*Folder Structure for View*

```
application

application > views > home.php
```

[*Models*](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model)

**File name:** Model_example.php

```
<?php

class Model_example extends CI_Model {

    public function get_results() {
      // Some Code Here.
    }
}
```

On your config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than uploading the codeigniter site directly you should be able to use something like Putty (http://www.putty.org/) to install a fresh version of Codeigniter through script and then add the files for your site to the installation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

The script used to install a fresh version of CI will differ based on what Linux platform you're using. wget is used for ubuntu.